# Attach js file to every page w/term reference widget in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms, javascript

I have begun trying to port a small, simple module that I maintain to Drupal 8.

It was originally written (not by me) in Drupal 6 and used `hook_init()` in combination with `drupal_add_js()` to attach its scripts to every page.

Both `hook_init()` and `drupal_add_js()` have been deprecated in Drupal 8. I only really need to attach scripts to pages that have a taxonomy term reference widget (and in fact much of my logic has already been moved into a `hook_field_widget_taxonomy_autocomplete_form_alter()`.) Scripts are now added via `#attached` which I understand, but since I don't have the `$form` array or object in `hook_field_widget_taxonomy_autocomplete_form_alter()` I'm not sure where to add the `#attached` element.

I'm also not clear if `#attached` is used *instead of* or *in addition to* a *.libraries.yml file. Does every single module with its own script.js need to declare a *.libraries.yml file?

How do I attach my custom js file to every page with a taxonomy term reference widget in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

'#attached' works for any element. You should have an element in scope in that alter hook. Also you should have a `mymodule.libraries.yml` to declare your script.

Comment: I have `mymodule.libraries.yml` and `hook_libraries_info()`. Still not attaching to my element.

Comment: You don't need hook_libraries_info(). You need to attach the library to the $element in your hook_field_widget_taxonomy_autocomplete_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's what I had to do. In mymodule.libraries.yml:

```
drupal.mymodule.widget:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/myscript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

In `hook_libraries_info()`: Nothing. I didn't use this.

In `hook_field_widget_taxonomy_autocomplete_form_alter()`:

```
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  $element['#attached']['js'][$path . '/js/myscript.js'] = array('every_page' => TRUE);
```

I'm still figuring out how exactly to get jQuery working in the script itself but this attaches the javascript to the page.

Comment: libraries.yml replaced hook_libraries_info(), so that is no longer required. You are not using your defined library either, which should not be named like this. base => drupal.yourmodule.something. Then instead of 'library' and specify the name of your library. See for example https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeForm.php/function/NodeForm%3A%3Aform/8 (search for #attached there)

Comment: So it should be like `base: drupal.mymodule.js:` instead of `base: js:` ?

Comment: not sure how you came up with base, you shouldn't have base at all. *instead* of base, have drupal.yourmodule.something.

Comment: You are still not actually using your defined library as you still reference your js file directly in #attached. You need to switch to something like [#attached][library][] = drupal.mymodule.widget;

Comment: When I do that it does not attach the js to the page. ` `$element['#attached']['library'][] = drupal.mymodule.widget;` in `hook_field_widget_taxonomy_autocomplete_form_alter()` and the js file is in mymodule/js/script.js.